# Is there a method to call activity back when onStop() immediately?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create an app that can't be stopped (send to background). Is there a method to achieve this? this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

but this code didnt respond immediately, I search everywehere for solution but get nothing. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean `onStopped()` method of application class or `onStop()` method of activity class?

Comment: sorry, i mean onStop